# Malformed PNG pixel data from deflate "unknown edge cases"

Tags: c, png, deflate, lz77

For the past 2 months, I've been implementing a png/deflate decoder, (for various reasons but mainly for learning purposes) but only returns the correct expected data in some cases.

Here in this table, I've gathered some details of the files (and the files themselves) that I've been using for the program in case you want to check them out:

| State | Image | Block type | Lz77 obtained (if fail) | Header info (Block type 2 only) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Works | [Color checker pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjHR7.png) | 2 |  | **HLIT:** *29*, **HDIST:** *23*, **HCLEN:** *14*, **Header cls:** *{0,3,3,3,3,4,0,4,0,3,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4}* |
| Works | [A grid with grayscale pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn0nJ.png) | 1 |  |  |
| Doesn't work | [10x10 noise image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXAwk.png) | 2 | 0 0 0 1 2 257 4 0 3 1 4 0 5 6 7 8 0 9 10 11 0 12 0 3 0 13 14 1 15 0 1 16 17 **258 -fails here [ 9 11 ]** **-Program attempts to read 36 symbols backwards on a 33 sized list** | **HLIT:** *2*, **HDIST:** *13*, **HCLEN:** *12*, **Header cls:** *{2,4,4,4,0,2,0,4,0,5,0,5,0,4,0,3}* |
| Doesn't work | [image: Some color palette] | 1 | 1 255 255 255 0 260 0 1 1 261 6 0 0 0 183 262 8 3 2 261 5 1 270 0 0 272 0 9 6 51 255 176 **266 0 -fails here [ 26 141 ]** **-Program attempts to read 8334 symbols backwards on a 34 sized list** |  |
| Returns malformed data | [Some random colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beIu7.png) | 2 | Possibly some data was malformed | **HLIT:** *4*, **HDIST:** *10*, **HCLEN:** *14*, **Header cls:** *{0,4,3,3,0,0,0,3,0,4,0,3,0,2,0,4,0,4}* |

Here is a snippet (or a MRE) of how I implemented deflate (The program needs the image path as a parameter; I tried my best to get it working with the fewest lines of code):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Quick table for ll distinction
uint16_t qtfld[5][2] = {
    {269,1},{273,2},
    {277,3},{281,4},
    {285,5}
};

//Quick table for distance distinction
uint8_t qtfdd[13][2] = {
    {6,1},{8,2},{9,3},
    {12,4},{14,5},{16,6},
    {18,7},{20,8},{22,9},
    {24,10},{26,11},{28,12},
    {30,13}
};

uint32_t FlipEndian(
    uint32_t value,
    uint32_t SToFlip
){
    if(SToFlip==0){return 0;}
    else{
        uint32_t reversed = 0;
        for(uint32_t w = 0; w <= SToFlip; w++){
            uint32_t lshift = 0;
            uint32_t rshift = 0;
            lshift = value<<(31-w);
            rshift = lshift>>31;
            reversed = (rshift<<((SToFlip-1)-w)) | reversed;
        }
        return reversed;
    }
}

uint16_t** GenCodes(
    uint16_t* cl_table,
    uint16_t* symbol_table,
    uint32_t both_tables_size
){
    //Finaltable
    uint32_t sizecodes = both_tables_size * sizeof(uint16_t*);
    uint16_t** codes = (uint16_t**)malloc(sizecodes);

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<both_tables_size; i++){
        codes[i] = (uint16_t*)malloc(3*sizeof(uint16_t));
    }

    //List for the sorting and frequency obtaining of the cl codes
    uint32_t size = both_tables_size*sizeof(uint16_t);
    int16_t* used_cls = (int16_t*)malloc(size);

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<both_tables_size; i++){
        used_cls[i] = -1;
    }

    //The aforementioned sorted cl table
    uint32_t cl_amount = 15*sizeof(uint16_t*);
    uint16_t** sorted_cl_frequencies = (uint16_t**)malloc(cl_amount);

    for(uint32_t c=0; c<15; c++){
        sorted_cl_frequencies[c] = (uint16_t*)malloc(2*sizeof(uint16_t));
    }

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<both_tables_size; i++){
        uint16_t min_cl = 15;
        uint8_t cl_usage = 0;

        for(uint32_t j=0; j<both_tables_size; j++){
            uint16_t current_cl = cl_table[i];

            for(uint32_t k=0; k<both_tables_size; k++){
                if(current_cl == used_cls[k]){
                    cl_usage = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(cl_usage==0){
                if(current_cl<min_cl){min_cl = current_cl;}
            }
        }

        if(cl_usage==0){
            uint32_t cl_counter = 0;

            for(uint32_t a=0; a<both_tables_size; a++){
                if(cl_table[a]==min_cl){cl_counter++;}
            }

            sorted_cl_frequencies[min_cl][0] = min_cl;
            sorted_cl_frequencies[min_cl][1] = cl_counter;
            used_cls[i] = min_cl;
        }
    }

    //Huffman code algorithm
    uint16_t code = 0;

    for(uint32_t i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        if(i<15){
            uint16_t prevfreq = sorted_cl_frequencies[i-1][1];
            uint16_t prevcl = sorted_cl_frequencies[i][0];
            code = (code + prevfreq) << 1;

            uint16_t aum = 0; 

            for(uint32_t j = 0;j<both_tables_size;j++){
                if(prevcl==cl_table[j]){
                    codes[j][0] = symbol_table[j];
                    codes[j][1] = cl_table[j];
                    codes[j][2] = FlipEndian(code+aum,cl_table[j]);
                    aum+=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<15; i++){
        free(sorted_cl_frequencies[i]);
    }    

    free(used_cls);
    free(sorted_cl_frequencies);
    return codes;
}

//OverallSlicedDataGathering
uint16_t OSDG(
    uint8_t* list, 
    uint32_t* biotl, //bitindexonthelist
    uint8_t sogd //sizeofgivendata
){
    uint32_t currentbyte = (uint32_t)floor((*biotl/8));
    uint32_t landingbyte = (uint32_t)floor((((*biotl-1)+sogd)/8));
    uint16_t final_data = 0;
   
    if(landingbyte>currentbyte){
        if(landingbyte>(currentbyte+1)){
            uint8_t bocb = 8-(*biotl%8);//bitsoncurrentbyte

            uint8_t slice1 = list[currentbyte]>>(8-bocb);

            uint8_t bonb = sogd-bocb;//bitsonnextbyte

            uint8_t slice2 = list[landingbyte] << (8-bonb);

            slice2 = slice2>>(8-bonb);

            uint16_t walls = 0;

            uint8_t middleslice = list[currentbyte+1];
            walls = (slice2<<(bocb+8)) | (middleslice<<bocb) | slice1;
            final_data = walls;
        }
        else{
            uint8_t bocb = 8-(*biotl%8);//bitsoncurrentbyte

            uint8_t slice1 = list[currentbyte]>>(8-bocb);

            uint8_t bonb = sogd-bocb;//bitsonnextbyte

            uint8_t slice2 = list[landingbyte] << (8-bonb);

            slice2 = slice2>>(8-bonb);

            uint16_t walls = 0;
            walls = (slice2<<(bocb)) | slice1;
            final_data = walls;
        }
    }
    else{
        //alongpartsifthereis
        uint8_t apiti = (*biotl%8)+sogd;
        
        //ShapedData
        uint8_t sd = list[currentbyte] << (8-apiti);

        sd = sd >> (8-sogd);
        final_data = (uint16_t)sd;
    }

    *biotl += sogd;
    return final_data; 
}

uint16_t* Obtain_CL_From_Bistream(
    uint16_t encoded_cls,
    uint16_t** codes,
    uint32_t size_of_codes,
    uint32_t* bit_index,
    uint8_t* idat_pointer
){
    uint32_t size = sizeof(uint16_t)*encoded_cls;
    uint16_t* finaltable = (uint16_t*)malloc(size);
    //skippedllsymbols
    int16_t sls = -1;
    
    for(uint16_t i=0; i<encoded_cls; i++){
        if(i>sls){
            for(uint32_t j=0; j<size_of_codes; j++){
                uint16_t cc = codes[j][2]; //currentcode
                uint16_t ccl = codes[j][1]; //currentcodelength
                uint16_t ccs = codes[j][0]; //currentcodesymbol

                //retrievedsymbolcodefrombitstream
                uint8_t rscfb = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,ccl);

                *bit_index-= ccl;

                if(rscfb==cc){
                    *bit_index += ccl;
                    //amountofsymbols
                    uint16_t aos = 0;

                    if(ccs==16){
                        uint8_t ntb = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,2);
                        aos = (ntb+3);

                        //previoussymbol
                        uint16_t ps = (uint16_t)(finaltable[i-1]);

                        for(uint16_t x=0 ;x<=aos; x++){
                            finaltable[i+x] = ps;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(ccs==17){
                        //nextthreebits
                        uint8_t ntrb = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,3);
                        aos = (ntrb+3);

                        for(uint16_t x=0; x<=aos; x++){
                            finaltable[i+x] = (uint16_t)(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(ccs==18){
                        //nextsevenbits
                        uint8_t nsb = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,7);
                        aos = (nsb+11);

                        for(uint16_t x=0; x<=aos; x++){
                            finaltable[i+x] = (uint16_t)(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        aos = 1;
                        finaltable[i] = (uint16_t)(ccs);
                    }
                    sls += aos;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return finaltable;
}

uint16_t* Uncompressed(
    uint32_t* bit_index,
    uint8_t* idat_pointer,
    uint32_t arbitrary_size
){
    *bit_index += 5;

    uint16_t len1 = idat_pointer[(uint32_t)floor((*bit_index/8))];
    uint16_t len2 = idat_pointer[(uint32_t)floor((*bit_index/8))+1];
    uint16_t LEN = (len1<<8)|(len2);

    *bit_index += 16;

    uint16_t nlen1 = idat_pointer[(uint32_t)floor((*bit_index/8))];
    uint16_t nlen2 = idat_pointer[(uint32_t)floor((*bit_index/8))+1];
    uint16_t NLEN = ~((nlen1<<8)|(nlen2));

    *bit_index += 16;

    uint32_t size = arbitrary_size*(sizeof(uint16_t));
    uint16_t* data = (uint16_t*)malloc(size);

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
    }

    if(LEN==NLEN){
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){
            data[i] = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,8);
        }
    }
    return data;
}

uint16_t* Static(
    uint32_t* bit_index,
    uint8_t* idat_pointer,
    uint32_t arbitrary_size
){
    uint32_t size = arbitrary_size*(sizeof(uint16_t));
    uint16_t* data = (uint16_t*)malloc(size);
    uint8_t EOT_found=0;

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){
        if(EOT_found){break;}
        uint8_t ignore=0;

        //newobtainedfixedvaluefrombitstream
        int16_t nofvfb = (int16_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,8);
        nofvfb = FlipEndian(nofvfb,8);
        *bit_index-=8;

        if((nofvfb-48)<=143 && (nofvfb-48)>=0){
            *bit_index+=8;
            data[i] = (nofvfb-48);
            ignore=1;
        }
        nofvfb = (int16_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,9);
        nofvfb = FlipEndian(nofvfb,9);
        *bit_index-=9;

        if((nofvfb-256)<=255 && (nofvfb-256)>=144){
            if(ignore==0){
                data[i] = (nofvfb-256);
                *bit_index+=9;
                ignore=1;
            }
        }
        nofvfb = (int16_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,7);
        nofvfb = FlipEndian(nofvfb,7);
        *bit_index-=7;

        if((nofvfb+256)<=279 && (nofvfb+256)>=256){
            if(ignore==0){
                *bit_index+=7;
                if((nofvfb+256)!=256){
                    data[i] = (nofvfb+256);
                    ignore=1;

                    if((nofvfb+256)>264 && (nofvfb+256)<285){
                        for(uint32_t j=0;j<5;j++){
                            if((nofvfb+256)<qtfld[j][0]){
                                i+=1;
                                //readoffsetbitsoflength
                                uint8_t robol = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,qtfld[j][1]);
                                data[i] = robol;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    i+=1;

                    //distancereturnedvaluebybits
                    uint8_t drvbb = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,5);
                    drvbb = FlipEndian(drvbb,5);
                    data[i] = drvbb;

                    if(drvbb>3){
                        for(uint32_t k=0;k<13;k++){
                            if(drvbb<qtfdd[k][0]){
                                i+=1;
                                //readoffsetbitsofdistance
                                uint8_t robod = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,qtfdd[k][1]);
                                data[i] = robod;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    data[i] = (nofvfb+256);
                    ignore=1;
                    EOT_found=1;
                }
            }
        }
    
        nofvfb = (int16_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,8);
        nofvfb = FlipEndian(nofvfb,8);
        *bit_index-=8;

        if((nofvfb+88)<=287 && (nofvfb+88)>=280){
            if(ignore==0){
                *bit_index+=8;

                data[i] = (nofvfb+88);
                ignore=1;
                
                if((nofvfb+88)>264 && (nofvfb+88)<285){
                    for(uint32_t j=0;j<5;j++){
                        if((nofvfb+88)<qtfld[j][0]){
                            i+=1;
                            //readoffsetbitsoflength
                            uint8_t robol = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,qtfld[j][1]);
                            data[i] = robol;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                i+=1;

                //distancereturnedvaluebybits
                uint8_t drvbb = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,5);
                drvbb = FlipEndian(drvbb,5);
                data[i] = drvbb;

                if(drvbb>3){
                    for(uint32_t k=0;k<13;k++){
                        if(drvbb<qtfdd[k][0]){
                            i+=1;
                            //readoffsetbitsofdistance
                            uint8_t robod = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,qtfdd[k][1]);
                            data[i] = robod;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}

uint16_t* Dynamic(
    uint32_t* bit_index,
    uint8_t* idat_pointer,
    uint32_t arbitrary_size
){
    uint8_t HLIT = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,5);
    printf("\nHLIT: %d",HLIT);
    uint8_t HDIST = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,5);
    printf("\nHDIST: %d",HDIST);
    uint8_t HCLEN = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,4);
    printf("\nHCLEN: %d",HCLEN);
    uint16_t newcl_clorder[19] = {16,17,18,0,8,7,9,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,2,14,1,15};
    //List of CLs
    uint16_t* CL_cl_lengths = (uint16_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*(HCLEN + 4));

    printf("\nHeader cls\n");
    uint8_t not_zero_cls_counter = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < (HCLEN + 4); i++){
        uint8_t CL_cl = (uint8_t)OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,3);

        CL_cl_lengths[newcl_clorder[i]] = CL_cl;
        printf("%d,",CL_cl_lengths[newcl_clorder[i]]);
        if(CL_cl!=0){
            not_zero_cls_counter++;
        }
    }

    uint32_t size = sizeof(uint16_t)*not_zero_cls_counter;
    //sorted header cl symbols
    uint16_t* shcs = (uint16_t*)malloc(size);
    //sorted header cl cl
    uint16_t* shcc = (uint16_t*)malloc(size);

    int8_t* used_cls = (int8_t*)malloc(sizeof(int8_t)*not_zero_cls_counter);

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<not_zero_cls_counter; i++){used_cls[i]=-1;}

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<not_zero_cls_counter; i++){
        uint8_t smallestsymbol = 18;
        uint8_t smallestsymbol_index = 2;

        for(uint8_t j=0; j<(HCLEN + 4); j++){
            uint8_t used_cls_usage = 0;
            uint16_t newavailablesymbol = newcl_clorder[j];

            for(uint8_t k=0; k<not_zero_cls_counter; k++){
                if(newavailablesymbol==used_cls[k]){
                    used_cls_usage = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(used_cls_usage==0){
                uint8_t newsymbcl = CL_cl_lengths[newcl_clorder[j]];
                if(newavailablesymbol<smallestsymbol && newsymbcl != 0){
                    smallestsymbol = newavailablesymbol;
                    smallestsymbol_index = j;
                }
            }
        }

        shcs[i] = newcl_clorder[smallestsymbol_index];
        shcc[i] = CL_cl_lengths[newcl_clorder[smallestsymbol_index]];
        used_cls[i] = newcl_clorder[smallestsymbol_index];
    }

    uint16_t** header_cl_symbols = GenCodes(shcc,shcs,not_zero_cls_counter); 

    ///////////Obtainingofllcodes
    uint16_t* zeroed_ll_cls = Obtain_CL_From_Bistream(
        (257+HLIT),header_cl_symbols,
        not_zero_cls_counter,
        bit_index,idat_pointer
    );

    uint16_t* ll_cl = (uint16_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*288);
    uint16_t* ll_symbols = (uint16_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*288);

    //finalsizeofnotzeroedlls
    uint32_t fsonzl = 0;
    uint32_t ll_omitter = 0;

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<(257+HLIT);i++){
        if(zeroed_ll_cls[i]!=0){
            ll_cl[i-ll_omitter] = zeroed_ll_cls[i];
            ll_symbols[i-ll_omitter]=i;
            fsonzl+=1;
        }
        else{ll_omitter+=1;}
    }

    uint16_t** ll_codes = GenCodes(ll_cl,ll_symbols,fsonzl);
    printf("\nLL generated codes:");
    for(uint32_t l=0; l<fsonzl; l++){
        printf("\nsymbol: %d, ",ll_codes[l][0]);
        printf("cl: %d, ",ll_codes[l][1]);
        printf("code: %d",ll_codes[l][2]);
    }

    ///////////Obtainingofdistcodes
    uint16_t* zeroed_dist_cls = Obtain_CL_From_Bistream(
        (HDIST+1),header_cl_symbols,
        not_zero_cls_counter,
        bit_index,idat_pointer
    );

    uint16_t* dist_cl = (uint16_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*32);
    uint16_t* dist_symbols = (uint16_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*32);

    //finalsizeofnotzeroeddist
    uint32_t fsonzd = 0;
    uint32_t dist_omitter = 0;

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<(HDIST+1);i++){
        if(zeroed_dist_cls[i]!=0){
            dist_cl[i-dist_omitter] = zeroed_dist_cls[i];
            dist_symbols[i-dist_omitter] = i;
            fsonzd+=1;
        }
        else{dist_omitter+=1;}
    }

    uint16_t** dist_codes = GenCodes(dist_cl,dist_symbols,fsonzd);
    printf("\nDistance generated codes:");
    for(uint32_t d=0; d<fsonzd; d++){
        printf("\nsymbol: %d, ",dist_codes[d][0]);
        printf("cl: %d, ",dist_codes[d][1]);
        printf("code: %d",dist_codes[d][2]);
    }

    ///////////bitstreamdecryption

    uint32_t bsize = arbitrary_size*(sizeof(uint16_t));
    uint16_t* data = (uint16_t*)malloc(bsize);

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){data[i]=0;}

    int ofsfld = -1;
    uint8_t megabreak = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){
        if(megabreak==1){break;}
        if(i>ofsfld){
            for(uint16_t j=0; j<=fsonzl; j++){
                uint16_t cc = ll_codes[j][2]; //currentcode
                uint16_t ccl = ll_codes[j][1]; //currentcodelength
                uint16_t ccs = ll_codes[j][0]; //currentcodesymbol

                //retrievedllsymbolcodefrombistream
                uint16_t rlscfb = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,ccl);
                *bit_index -= ccl;

                if(rlscfb==cc){
                    *bit_index += ccl;
                    data[i] = ccs;
                    ofsfld+=1;

                    if(ccs==256){megabreak=1;break;}
                    if(ccs>256){
                        uint8_t aum = 0;
                                
                        if(ccs>264 && ccs!=285){
                            for(uint8_t t=0; t<5; t++){
                                if(ccs<qtfld[t][0]){
                                    //readoffset
                                    data[(i+1)] = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,qtfld[t][1]);
                                    aum=1;
                                    ofsfld+=1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        for(uint32_t k=0; k<=fsonzd; k++){
                            uint16_t dcc = dist_codes[k][2]; //distancecc
                            uint16_t dccl = dist_codes[k][1]; //distanceccl
                            uint16_t dccs = dist_codes[k][0]; //distanceccs

                            //retrieveddistancesymbolcodefrombistream
                            uint8_t rdscfb = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,dccl);
                            *bit_index -= dccl;

                            if(rdscfb==dcc){
                                *bit_index += dccl;
                                ofsfld += 1;

                                data[(i+(1+aum))] = dccs;

                                if(dccs>3){
                                    for(uint8_t e=0; e<13; e++){
                                        if(dccs<qtfdd[e][0]){
                                            //readoffset
                                            data[(i+(2+aum))] = OSDG(idat_pointer,bit_index,qtfdd[e][1]);
                                            ofsfld += 1;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<not_zero_cls_counter; i++){
        free(header_cl_symbols[i]);
    }   
    free(header_cl_symbols);

    free(CL_cl_lengths);
    free(shcs);
    free(shcc);
    free(used_cls);
    
    free(ll_symbols);
    free(ll_cl);

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<fsonzl; i++){
        free(ll_codes[i]);
    }
    free(ll_codes);

    free(dist_symbols);
    free(dist_cl);

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<fsonzd; i++){
        free(dist_codes[i]);
    }
    free(dist_codes);

    return data;
}

uint16_t lengthAr[29][2] = {
    {257,3},    {258,4},
    {259,5},    {260,6},
    {261,7},    {262,8},
    {263,9},    {264,10},    
    {265,11},    {266,13},    
    {267,15},    {268,17},    
    {269,19},    {270,23},    
    {271,27},    {272,31},    
    {273,35},    {274,43},    
    {275,51},    {276,59},    
    {277,67},    {278,83},    
    {279,99},    {280,115},    
    {281,131},    {282,163},    
    {283,195},    {284,227},    
    {285,258}
};

uint16_t distanceAr[30][2] = {
    {0,1},    {1,2},
    {2,3},    {3,4},
    {4,5},    {5,7},
    {6,9},    {7,13},
    {8,17},    {9,25},
    {10,33},    {11,49},
    {12,65},    {13,97},
    {14,129},    {15,193},
    {16,257},    {17,385},
    {18,513},    {19,769},
    {20,1025},    {21,1537},
    {22,2049},    {23,3073},
    {24,4097},    {25,6145},
    {26,8193},    {27,12289},
    {28,16385},    {29,24577}
};

uint8_t* Lz77(
    uint16_t* lz77_pointer,
    uint32_t arbitrary_size
){
    //currentindexfordecrypteddata
    uint32_t cifdd = 0;

    uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*)malloc(arbitrary_size*sizeof(uint8_t));

    //lengtharraysizeonvariable
    uint16_t lason = (uint16_t)floor((sizeof(lengthAr)/sizeof(lengthAr[0])));

    //distancearraysizeonvariable
    uint16_t dason = (uint16_t)floor((sizeof(distanceAr)/sizeof(distanceAr[0])));

    uint8_t megabreak = 0;

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){
        printf("\ndata at %d: %d",i,lz77_pointer[i]);
        if(lz77_pointer[i]==256 || megabreak==1){break;}
        if(lz77_pointer[i]>256){
            uint32_t rs = 0; //repeatsize
            int dtg = 0; //distancetogo

            for(uint16_t j=0; j<lason; j++){
                if(lz77_pointer[i]==lengthAr[j][0]){
                    i+=1;

                    //offsetbitslength
                    uint16_t obl = 0;
                    if(lengthAr[j][0]>264 && lengthAr[j][0] != 285){
                        obl = lz77_pointer[i];
                        i+=1;
                    }

                    rs = (lengthAr[j][1])+obl;

                    for(uint16_t k=0; k<dason; k++){
                        if(lz77_pointer[i]==distanceAr[k][0]){
                            uint16_t obd = 0;

                            if(distanceAr[k][0]>3){
                                i+=1;
                                obd = lz77_pointer[i];
                            }

                            dtg = (distanceAr[k][1])+obd;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            printf("\nLength: %d",rs);
            printf("\nDistance: %d",dtg);

            int backpos = cifdd-dtg;

            if(backpos<0){
                printf("\nERROR: Reading negative indexes");
                break;
            }

            for(uint32_t s=0; s<rs; s++){
                data[cifdd+s] = data[backpos+s];   
            }

            cifdd+=rs;
        }
        else{
            data[cifdd] = lz77_pointer[i];
            cifdd += 1;
        }
    }
    return data;
}

int main(
    int nop, //numberofparameters
    char** pl //parameterlist
){
    uint8_t png[32768];
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(pl[1],"r");

    fread(png,sizeof(uint8_t),32768,fp);
    fclose(fp);

    uint32_t idatsize = 0;
    uint8_t* idatpointer = NULL;

    for(uint32_t i=8; i<32768; i++){
        uint32_t chunksize = (png[i]<<24)|(png[i+1]<<16)|(png[i+2]<<8)|(png[i+3]);
        
        i += 4;
        if(png[i]==73 && png[i+1]==68 && png[i+2]==65 && png[i+3]==84){
            idatpointer = (uint8_t*)malloc((chunksize-6)*sizeof(uint8_t));
        }

        i += 4;
        if(idatpointer!=NULL){
            for(uint32_t j=0;j<chunksize-4;j++){
                idatpointer[j] = png[(i+2)+j];
            }
            break;
        }

        i += chunksize;
        i += 3;
    }

    uint32_t imgx = (png[16]<<24)|(png[17]<<16)|(png[18]<<8)|(png[19]);
    uint32_t imgy = (png[20]<<24)|(png[21]<<16)|(png[22]<<8)|(png[23]);
    uint32_t colortype = png[25];

    uint8_t samples_per_pixel = 0;
    if(colortype==0){samples_per_pixel=1;}
    else if(colortype==2){samples_per_pixel=3;}
    else if(colortype==3){samples_per_pixel=1;}
    else if(colortype==4){samples_per_pixel=2;}
    else if(colortype==6){samples_per_pixel=4;}
    
    uint32_t bit = 0;
    uint8_t islastbit = (uint8_t)OSDG(idatpointer,&bit,1);
    uint8_t btype = (uint8_t)OSDG(idatpointer,&bit,2);
    printf("\nbtype: %d",btype);

    uint16_t* lz77_pointer = NULL;
    uint32_t arbitrary_size = (((imgx*imgy)*samples_per_pixel)+imgy)+idatsize;

    if(btype==0){lz77_pointer = Uncompressed(&bit,idatpointer,arbitrary_size);}
    else if(btype==1){lz77_pointer = Static(&bit,idatpointer,arbitrary_size);}
    else if(btype==2){lz77_pointer = Dynamic(&bit,idatpointer,arbitrary_size);}

    printf("\nLzz7 symbols: ");
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){
        printf("%d ",lz77_pointer[i]);
    }

    uint8_t* deencryped_data = Lz77(lz77_pointer,arbitrary_size);

    printf("\nDecompressed data: ");
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i<arbitrary_size; i++){
        printf("%d ",deencryped_data[i]);
    }

    int8_t c = getchar();
    free(deencryped_data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253599/discussion-on-question-by-makset-malformed-png-pixel-data-from-deflate-unknown); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal fix for the chunk decoder to avoid the buffer overflow:

```
const uint8_t signature[8] = {137, 'P', 'N', 'G', '\r', '\n', 26, '\n' };
#define CHUNK_LENGTH_LEN 4
#define CHUNK_TYPE_LEN 4
#define CHUNK_CRC_LEN 4
#define COMPRESSION_METHOD_FLAGS_CODE_LEN 1
#define ADDITIONAL_FLAGS_CHECK_BITS_LEN 1
#define CHECK_VALUE_LEN 4

// ...
    uint8_t *idatpointer = NULL;
    for(uint32_t i=sizeof(signature);;) {
        uint32_t chunksize = (png[i]<<24)|(png[i+1]<<16)|(png[i+2]<<8)|(png[i+3]);
        i += CHUNK_LENGTH_LEN;

        if(!strncmp((char *) png + i, "IDAT", CHUNK_TYPE_LEN)) {
            idatpointer = png + i + CHUNK_TYPE_LEN + COMPRESSION_METHOD_FLAGS_CODE_LEN + ADDITIONAL_FLAGS_CHECK_BITS_LEN;
        }
        if(!strncmp((char *) png + i, "IEND", CHUNK_TYPE_LEN))
            break;
        i += CHUNK_TYPE_LEN;
        i += chunksize;
        i += CHUNK_CRC_LEN;
    }
```

Just like the original it does not handle multiple IDAT chunks.

I have been testing with the 10x10 noise image, and it appears to be blocktype 1 (not 2 as indicated in the table).

The result from `Static(&bit,idatpointer,arbitrary_size)` (you print the same data just as decimal instead of hex):

```
(gdb) x/55xh lz77_pointer
0x55555555b890: 0x0072  0x011e  0x0011  0x0024  0x0108  0x0002  0x0114  0x0002
0x55555555b8a0: 0x0010  0x0062  0x001b  0x000c  0x0117  0x0000  0x000e  0x0028
0x55555555b8b0: 0x005e  0x0068  0x000b  0x0089  0x00bf  0x00ee  0x011f  0x0019
0x55555555b8c0: 0x004d  0x007a  0x0024  0x00a2  0x0100  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000
0x55555555b8d0: 0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000
0x55555555b8e0: 0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000
0x55555555b8f0: 0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000
```

doesn't match the result I get from writing out the 96 bytes of IDAT chunk data to a file then decompressing it with `pigz -d < idat.in | xxd`:

```
00000000: 0000 0001 0200 0000 0301 0400 0506 0708  ................
00000010: 0009 0a0b 000c 0003 000d 0e01 0f00 0110  ................
00000020: 1100 0000 0312 1314 1514 030a 0016 1718  ................
00000030: 0300 0000 191a 1b00 0114 1c01 1d1e 031f  ................
00000040: 1400 0014 1401 2000 2122 0023 2400 2500  ...... .!".#$.%.
00000050: 2627 0100 0028 0329 0003 2a2b 142c 002d  &'...(.)..*+.,.-
00000060: 2e00 2f00 1430 0000 0114 3132 0133       ../..0....12.3
```

Note that I didn't reverse the filter byte (0x00)[1](http://libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IHDR) on each scan line (i.e. remove 10i'th byte).  If I did the first 4 bytes would be: 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x02 which clearly doesn't match 0x00 0x72 x01 0x1e.

Looking at the [DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification version 1.3](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/RFC-1951#fixed) those magic numbers look about right for the fixed huffman codes (3.2.6) except the `if((nofvfb+256)>264 && (nofvfb+256)<285){` and the  `if((nofvfb+88)<=287 && (nofvfb+88)>=280 && !ignore){` blocks but I haven't studied it.  This should help you a large step forward.  I don't know why you need to add those offset before comparing the lit value.  If you want to use your own LZ77 implementation I suggest you test it independently.  You could also consider using zlib (or other existing implementation instead of writing your at least a stepping stone.

Comment: Wait, btype 1? In theory, after the idat name (`73 68 65 84` or `49 44 38 54` in hex) you should have face `24 87` (hex `18 57`) which is the zlib stuff, therefore ignored, then a `21` (hex `15`, binary `0001 0101`) appears, which tells: is the last block `1`, and is btype 2 `10` when reading as lsb, and according to the deflate spec, only huffman codes are read as msb. Now I'm more intrigued. :o